# Show, using the mean value theorem and given $|f(x)-f(y)| ≤ |x-y|^3$ and $x, y ∈ [0,1]$, that $f(x)$ has to be constant.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, inequality, problem-solving

Show, using the mean value theorem and given $|f(x)-f(y)| ≤ |x-y|^3$ and $x, y ∈ [0,1]$, that $f(x)$ has to be constant.

For which $a > 0$ does the same inference apply, given $|f(x)-f(y)| ≤ |x-y|^a$?

Comment: For a>1, f is differentiable and the derivative vanishes. Moreover f is absolutely continuous.

Comment: make sure you've seen all posts like this before posting